# particle.js as div background issue

Tags: html, css, particles.js

My idea is to keep particle.js as the background for the sidebar. I tried many solutions but none of them actually worked for my idea.

Here is the link to my site
https://vchrombie.github.io/blog/

Below are the links to the files

https://github.com/vchrombie/blog/blob/gh-pages/_sass/pages/_layout.scss
https://github.com/vchrombie/blog/blob/gh-pages/_layouts/default.html

(I don't think the below file is neccessary, correct me if I am wrong.."
https://github.com/vchrombie/blog/blob/gh-pages/_includes/sidebar.html

Is it possible to keep the particle.js as the background only for the sidebar? 
I am really stuck for two days. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: If you downloaded standard particles from https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/ what you need to do is to include <div id="particles-js"></div> where you want particles to appear. If you place it between body tags it particles will be on the entire page. If you place it between header tags, particles will be only in header etc.

Comment: I don't want for the whole page, I just want to keep it for the sidebar.
Is it possible?